# COM Exception : 0x800AC472 raised when System is Locked (Excel VSTO)

Tags: c#, com, vsto, excel-interop, comexception

I'm using a 2D array to write data to an excel range. It works as expected when the system is not in Locked State.The code looks something like this:

```
Range range = SetRange(); // no. of rows and columns in the selected range is equal to the no.of rows and columns in the 2D Array 
object[,] data = new object[rows, columns];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        data[i, j] = i+j;
    }
}
range.value2 = data;
```

The operation "range.value2 = data" gets executed without any issues when the system is not locked. However, when I lock the system and this operation is attempted, I get an exception message "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472" when executing this operation.

I understand that this is a COM Exception but I don't have any idea, why is it getting raised under these circumstances. This issue only  happens when my system is in locked state. Otherwise, the same piece of code works fine.

I'm currently working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft Excel 2007.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception (HRESULT: 0x800AC472) when using Excel.Worksheet.Select after calling Excel.Workbook.SaveAs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737432/exception-hresult-0x800ac472-when-using-excel-worksheet-select-after-calling)

Comment: Hi Tomasz. In my case, this issue occurs when my machine gets locked. Otherwise, the code works fine. This is not a duplicate of the link above.