# C# HRESULT 0x800AC472 when creating a new Workbooks with Excel Interop

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, excel-interop

Until recently, this scheduled C# console application worked pretty well but since something like 2 weeks, it crash at the beginning of the code where I start using Excel Interop.

When running it myself it works well, but when I try to execute it through the Scheduled Task Manager (same problem on both **Windows Server 2008 r2**  and **Windows Server 2016**, both have Excel properly installed and a valid licence key) it crash just after I tryed to start it.

(Sorry if there's mystakes or else, I'm not really used to write "real" English, if anything isn't clear don't be afraid to ask for explaination).

The Scheduled Task Manager point that the program return error 0xE0434352. I already searched a bit for that, and found that it's actually a generic error number. So I added an AppDomain catcher to get the proper error number in a log file. I now know that the true error is the "HRESULT : 0x800AC472" and throw at :

> wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

I already tested to declare an empty workbook then add a sheet in it, or use "XlSheetType.xlWorksheet" instead of "XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet" but still the same. Only one time it passed but got same error on :

> ws.Name = "Name";

I also read about a stackoverflow error but there's only one Excel proceses created, and i tryed to add a Thread.Sleep(50//500//5000) but it didn't changed anything.
Here's the code part where it crash, I don't think anyother part of the code is needed :

```
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        String part = "";
        String pathD = "";
        List<Part> partList = new List<Part>();
        int ligne = 1;
        Workbook wb = null;
        Worksheet ws = null;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEL could not be started. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
            return;
        }
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        foreach (StockRow stockRow in Requete.getStockRows())
        {
            if (stockRow.Part != part)
            {
                partList.Add(new Part(stockRow.PartCode, stockRow.Part));
                if (wb != null)
                {
                    ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[ligne, 9]].entirecolumn.autofit();
                    ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[ligne, 9]].entirerow.autofit();
                    ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[ligne, 9]].verticalalignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathD))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathD);
                    }
                    wb.SaveAs(pathD + "\\Stock_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH") + "h.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue, misValue, false, false,
                        XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    wb.Close();
                }

                pathD = path + stockRow.PartCode;
                wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
                ws.Name = "Name";
                ws.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
                ligne = 1;
                ws.Cells[ligne, 1] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 2] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 3] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 4] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 5] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 6] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 7] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 8] = "Column Name";
                ws.Cells[ligne, 9] = "Column Name";

                //codes continue ...
            }
            // codes continue ...
        }
        // codes continue ...
```

I'd obviously like to find why this is now not working anymore, and even if u don't have the perfect answer, even a hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot for reading until here.

Comment: Can you run it in the console outside of the task scheduler on the target host?

Comment: You say you're running this on a server - could it be related to Excel trying to show a dialog box, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737432/exception-hresult-0x800ac472-when-using-excel-worksheet-select-after-calling)?

Comment: The usual response to trying to automate Excel on a shared server like this is *don't*. It's really not safe at all.

Comment: @DavidG is right. Microsoft are clear that [automating Office on a server is not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

Comment: TheIncorrigible1 : Yes, and it run exactly as expected
@DavidG : I'm not the one who decided that, and I can't really tell them not to do that

Comment: @stuartd I don't know, there's the "xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;" which should prevent Excel to try to open dialog

Comment: basically you are not freeing the COM objects you acquired. After doing that too many times Excel blows up

Comment: @Steve actualy (thx to the log file i created) i know it crash at the very first loop, so it shouldn't be that problem :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Excel manually **on the server** and do the steps that your application does manually. Be sure to use the same user account that the task scheduler uses to run your program. It's highly recommended to use an actual user account instead of some built-in service account.

If you really need to use a built-in account like "SYSTEM", you need to make sure that there's nothing wrong with C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile, like a missing Desktop folder.

Maybe Excel crashed and tries to ask you to restore the last document, thereby blocking any progress. Sometimes weird things happen when you use automation without a UI. Comments saying that unattended automation, especially on servers, should be avoided, are correct. A more stable way is to use a library that can access XLSX documents and do your modifications there. We use server-side office automation to publish Word and PowerPoint to PDF and XPS files, and that already randomly fails whenever Office feels like it.

If everything fails, use a completely new user account on the server in which to run the application and thus Excel. Usually it's something wrong with Excel itself, which you can't do anything about in your code, and lacking a UI, not do much debugging either.

If you can't access the server on which Excel runs, there is no way for you to reproduce the behavior and you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm familiar with [this PowerShell module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) that interacts with excel files without office installed.  I think it's a wrapper for `EPPlus.dll`

Comment: You can simply use the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk?view=openxml-2.8.1) which is provided by Microsoft, as long as you don't need to do much more than dumping data into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf I'll try to do steps manually, thx for the idea, I will come back to tell you what comes out

Comment: @AlexanderGräf I tryed to do it manually using the same user as the scheduled task, but everything worked fine, no dialog boxes or else, even if I leave Excel processes that are left alive by the program

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer What user account does the application run with when started from the Task Scheduler?

Comment: @AlexanderGräf it's a "normal" admin user, which is the one others dev and me use to connect to the server with RDS, and is also the one used for every scheduled program on this server (we do not have super admin access)

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer So it's an actual user. That's good. You need to find out why Excel suddenly behaves differently with that user. There can be any number of changes, especially if it's an account that is regularly used for logons. Try a different user to run the task on the server. There is really no good way to debug this. Install Sysinternals Process Monitor and look through access to the registry and file system. Compare to what happens when run from the console instead of the task scheduler.

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer and disable all Add-Ins, extensions in Office etc. Maybe a software was installed that loads with Excel which doesn't run properly without a real, interactive session. Microsoft has it's own components like SharePoint, OneDrive. Acrobat might also be a candidate, as well as printer drivers.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf thanks for the tips, I'll try to debug with Process Monitor during lunch time as there's too much activity for now. This program interact with SharePoint, so after debug with the Monitor i'll try to disable all of these

Comment: @AlexanderGräf I tested the Monitor, but i didn't saw much differences between manual launch and scheduled task, in both there's a lot of Excel event with results "Buffer too small" and "Buffer overflow"

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer Did you try it with a completely new user profile on the server? Next step after that might be completely removing and reinstalling Office. You really need to look closely at the logs by Process Monitor. In the example above about the SYSTEM profile, it was just a missing, empty folder in the profile that completely made Excel stop.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf Do you know if there is a precise filter for Monitor i can add to avoid reading 90k lines and still let me see the problem ? (for example, what was the exact result ?)

And actually we got the servers here, but we're not the ones managing it, and as I said before we don't have another user acount that can log in the server directly, for that we would have to ask to the compagny managing it.

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer first you filter for excel.exe. Select only registry and file access. If anything, you're looking for access denied or file not found. But if your company doesn't manage the server, it could be any number of things, including newly added group policies, updates and additional software. If I were you, I'd either already request a dedicated user to run Excel with, or start with adapting a solution with Open XML SDK.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf Ok, i guess that we'll ask for that Excel user. And as i'm on this for some hours now, my collegues decided to give the problem directly to the company which is managing the server. If they find it would be nice, but else we're gonna request this user.

Thanks a lot for taking so much time to help me, I'll mark your answer as the one to our problem

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer You're welcome, I'm sorry there is no definitive answer to your problem. Know you know why Microsoft does not support running automation on servers.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf Don't worry, if we can't fix it on the server, I guess we'll get a new PC dedicated to scheduled task. I didn't though it could be that tricky to correct it, even if Interop sometimes react in unexpected and strange ways

Comment: Thanks man! For us it was the license dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You NEED to free up the COM objects after finish using them or else it would cause the process to stay alive even after you called close.

If you acquired too many COM objects without freeing then Excel will blow up completely (heap corruption, access violation, memory corruption, ect).

for example

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Add
```

would result in a guarantee COM leak. `xlApp.Workbooks` would acquire a `Workbooks` COM object but you are not storing the reference to it.

you would want to do

```
var workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
wb = workbooks.Add(...);
```

and then when you are done using workbooks

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
```

Do this on every single COM object that you acquire. I.E. anything that belongs to the `Interop.Excel` namespace

The easiest way to find out if you have COM leak is to check task manager to see if your application's process stays alive after exit. (assuming you are not doing a force kill like `Environment.Exit` or `Process.Kill`)

Comment: I tryed to add this for every COM objects (even those which aren't showed in the code I posted up there) but it still don't work (as I answer to you in the "main" post, it crash at the first loop) and i still got Excel processes that are left alive when the program die

Comment: When your application crashes, there is a pretty high chance you're leaving object references not released, unless you really put effort into it. But leaked references aren't your problem. At least not right now. But you need to fix it in the long run.

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer If you see excel process left over then it means you still got COM leak. period. After too many leaks the serve exception might even corrupt Excel's internal buffer array causing any COM operation to throw exception. Try restarting your server first and reinstall Excel if it still doesnt work.

Comment: @Steve That's not how COM works, that's not how COM HRESULT return codes work, and that's also not how reference leaks work. They are completely harmless unless their resource consumption poses a problem or a resource lock needs to be released, i.e. an opened file. On the opposite, unintentionally releasing an object that was already released might very well corrupt memory, and at the very least produce exceptions.

Comment: @AlexanderGräf thats not how COM works but thats how Excel works. Have seen multiple real life examples already. COM leak for Excel is super dangerous

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we migrated to a new server and installed office 2016. Office requires the user to accept the license agreement. What fixed my issue was to log in using Remote desktop and the credentials of the ID running the scheduled task.  Open Excel and try to enter some text and save the file.  Office prompted to accept the license. Once accepted, the scheduled task ran as expected.  I believe the  Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472 was due to office waiting for the prompt to accept the license.