# Handling exception (0x800AC472) in Excel Application.ScreenUpdating

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am writing a `C#` `VSTO` `Excel` Addin.
In my project, there is a requirement to update and merge a large number of cells.

In order to reduce the flickering and improve the performance, I am setting Application.ScreenUpdating to `false` before and setting back to `true` after the operation has completed.

The problem is that sometimes I get an exception setting back to `true` state.

Error Message :

> (HRESULT: 0x800AC472) (VBA_E_IGNORE).

In this case, the Excel is stuck (since there is no screen updating) and the only choice is to quit/reopen the Excel.

Here is my code:

```
 Excel.Application app = somevalue;
    try
    {
        app.ScreenUpdating = false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.LogExceptionError($"SafeEnableScreenUpdating -> param={enable}");
    }

    ... some large operation.

    try
    {
        app.ScreenUpdating = true;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // exception is here.
        e.LogExceptionError($"SafeEnableScreenUpdating");
    }
```

The only possible solution I found so far is to make a loop and try to restore the state a few times.
Has anyone experienced such problem?

Comment: I would set this up using a [Background Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8). Also you can add in a [Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) to reset the screen updating.

Comment: Not sure how Finally could help here? The operation fails in a call  app.ScreenUpdating = true; -> it would have the same behaviour in finally block as well.

Comment: Sorry missed that part, on my phone. I'd still check out the background worker. Running the procedure in a separate thread may help.

Comment: What happens when you also set the "Visible" flag to false while updating.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably a dialog window is displayed at the time of `ScreenUpdating` call. You may find a similar exception described in the  [Exception (HRESULT: 0x800AC472) when using Excel.Worksheet.Select after calling Excel.Workbook.SaveAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737432/exception-hresult-0x800ac472-when-using-excel-worksheet-select-after-calling) page.

Also, I'd recommend setting the `CalculationMode` and `EnableEvents` properties:

```
Sub YourSub()
    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Code here

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Do error handling
    GoTo CleanUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps someone:
I've used a Excel-DNA helper function `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro` to execute the `ScreenUpdating` enable/disable operation.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/wiki/COM-object-model-notes):

> This waits for Excel to be ready, then runs the delegate you pass. In
>   there, you can use the object model

So my code looks like (I am calling this function before and after the operation):

```
ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro(state =>
{
    try
    {
        app.ScreenUpdating = (bool)state;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.LogExceptionError($"ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro");
    }
}, enable); // enable can be true or false.
```