# Not able to open Excel workbook from Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to read data from Excel sheet through Windows service. But, I am not able to read it. The same code is working properly in Windows Form. But, in Windows service, it is not working properly.

```
filepath="path of excelsheet";
var app =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
var exbk = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
```

I am getting Error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
```

Comment: include a little bit of your code to see what you did

Comment: filepath="path of excelsheet";
var app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
var exbk = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath);

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737432/exception-hresult-0x800ac472-when-using-excel-worksheet-select-after-calling