# C# Exporting from database to excel returns a hexadecimal error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am reading a List from my database and I only need to export 1 column of this data into an excel sheet. However, the try catch method is catching the following Hex error "0x800AC472".

```
        try
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Data.xlsx";
            var listOfUsers = _context.Users.ToList();

            int row = 2;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelCellrange;

            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = false;
            excel.Interactive = false;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
            excelSheet.Name = "Test work sheet";
            excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[listOfUsers.Count, 1]];
            excelCellrange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            excelSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Phone Number";

            foreach (var user in listOfUsers)
            {
                excelSheet.Cells[row, 1] = user.PhoneNumber;
                row++;
            }

            excelSheet.SaveAs(path);

            return Ok();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message); ;
        }
```

Update:

Turns out the issue was in MS Office license. It was expired. Once I fixed the license everything worked out.

Comment: No accepted answer, here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737432/exception-hresult-0x800ac472-when-using-excel-worksheet-select-after-calling, but maybe answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/hresult-800ac472-from-set-operations-in-excel?forum=vsto it seems that this error is a result of excel wanting to prompt the user for some sort of input but being unable to.

Consider instead using a library like EPPlus instead. Watch out of the licensing though, it changed from LGPL to Polyform from version 5. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.3.3

Comment: Actually it turns out that the issue was with MS Office license. It was expired. Once I fixed this issue the error was gone

Comment: That makes sense, an expired license would cause a prompt to the user if you were doing this manually rather than programmatically.